# How can templatized dojo widgets recognize non-dojo attributes?

Tags: dojo, widget

I'd like to create a templatized dojo widget and use it in a form field as I show below.  However, the path attribute never gets set.  How do I do that?

HTML

```
   <form:input id="firstName" path="firstName" data-dojo-type="custom.myWidget"/>
```

WIDGET HTML

```
   <div>
        <form:errors path="${!path}"/>
    </div>
```

WIDGET JAVASCRIPT

```
define([
        "dojo/_base/declare", 
        "dijit/form/TextBox", 
        "dijit/_Templated"], 
function(declare, TextBox){

        return declare("custom.myWidget", TextBox,{

                    path:"",      

                    _setPathAttr:function(value){
                        this._set("path",value);
                    }
          });

});
```

Comment: Is `${!path}` left in the HTML? What happens? Also, you seem to require `dijit/_Templated` but don't actually use it anywhere. I think you need to read this - https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html.

Comment: When I inspect the element it shows something like: <form:errors path/>.  I believe _Templated is used in the JS elsewhere, just not in this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

i dont get whats your mean about non-dojo attr but you can set props using dojo declarative syntax like this:

```
<form:input id="firstName" data-dojo-type="custom.myWidget" data-dojo-props="path: 'firstName'">
```